# Disable Visual Studio (ReSharper?) editor tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, tooltip, mouseover

When I mouseover a method in my line of code, VS2010 shows a tooltip that tells me information about the signature and documentation of the method.

How can I disable these tooltips (maybe ReSharper is showing them?)?

Comment: For posterity, in my case, the offending tooltip came from Productivity Power Tools.  To disable: Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Solution Navigator > Enable interactive tooltips.

Comment: Check out the solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4131052/352640 This worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only "solution" I have found to this problem is to go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# and disable the "Parameter Information" option.  It seems that there is a bug in Resharper that keeps turning the option back on periodically (maybe on restart of VS), but where the tooltip is really annoying it is worth turning off repeatedly.

Comment: The reverse seems to be the case now - when I disabled resharper I lost both the resharper tooltips AND the Visual Studio ones. Used your pointer to find out how to turn the VS defaults back on until I can get myself a licensed copy of Resharper.

Comment: the reverse is the same with me, with the newest version of Resharper (6.1)

Comment: This works in Visual Studio 2015 as well. The Menu has changed though. Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages and disable the "Parameter Information" option to get rid of the annoying tool-tips!