# How do I turn off code tooltips in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It seems wherever my mouse is in my code window it will bring up tooltip information about what's under it, this I find very distracting and quite annoying. Can anyone tell me how to turn off the tooltips in the editor?

**EDIT**: Clarification, for C#

Comment: are you talking tooltips when you hover over actual code? menu items? icons? i doubt there is a global `no tooltips` switch.

Comment: Microsoft intended to make us suffer.  It is awful I put up with that thing every hour of my programming.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I created an extension that disables quick info for C#: [DisableQuickInfo.vsix](https://github.com/downloads/NoahRic/Random/DisableQuickInfo.vsix).

The [source](https://github.com/NoahRic/Random/blob/master/DisableQuickInfo.cs) is pretty simple, just a quick info source that immediately dismisses the session it gets.  You can modify it pretty easily to apply to any language, if you have the SDK installed.  Let me know if you want help with that.

---

Original answer, for C/C++:

What language?  For C/C++, for example, you'd set `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Auto Quick Info` to `False`.  I think it's one of the few languages you can disable it for.

(It's called "Quick Info", for future reference)

Comment: brilliant, and darn at the same time, I'm looking for C#. The options dialog within VS has always been a frustratingly inconsistent dialog. Your help is appreciated Noah.

Comment: I think I have an extension workaround that disables it.  I'll update my answer with a link in a second.

Comment: There, added an extension that should disable it for C#.  Let me know if it works for you (or not, and I can fix it).

Comment: Fantastic Noah, thank you so much for your help, I am very appreciative of this, I don't ever remember it being so annoying within 2008/5/3.

Comment: It's possible that the hover delay has gotten shorter, but I thought that it was set to match Orcas (in really early builds, it was a 1-2 second delay for the tip to come up, which annoyed people *a lot*).

Comment: I shouldn't be surprised, but it doesn't install for VS2012, maybe it's a new question in itself, but anyone know of the exactly same functionality for Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: @PandaWood 4 years later.. Did you find anything? :)

Comment: I have a Visual Studio 2019 Pro now. Those pop up balloons are like wildfire popping up everywhere your mouse went. It is DISTRACTING! I almost have to doubt microsoft's IDE developers have an intention to torture their users developers so they would change to other IDE's.