# How can I turn off the Visual Studio tooltip?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, productivity-power-tools

I have Visual Studio 2010 and I have installed the [Productivity PowerTools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).

Visual Studio QuickInfo is hiding Power Tools interactive tooltips: When I hover over the a variable I get 2 tooltips, and the one from Visual Studio is covering up the PowerTools interactive tooltip.

How can I turn off the Visual Studio tooltip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I solved it by using the little Visual Studio extension Noah Richards posted as an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130598/how-do-i-turn-off-code-tooltips-in-visual-studio-2010)
Just download the *DisableQuickInfo.vsix* file and install it. The tooltips (or quickinfo as they are called) should be gone.

Comment: You need to change the extension on the file from .zip to .vsix

Comment: It would be great if someone could update this for VS2012 (I have the extension mentioned installed, and it doesn't work)